# How to reduce width of outlined material icon?

Tags: html, css, material-ui, icons, google-material-icons

Is there any way to make this icon look thinner? font-weight and stroke-width is not working.

```css
.material-icons-outlined,
.material-icons.material-icons--outlined {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Outlined';
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight:100;
  stroke-width: 0.1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500|Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp">
</head>

<body>

  <section id="outlined">
    <h2>Outlined</h2>
    <i class="material-icons material-icons--outlined">assignment</i>
  </section>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) OR [scale()](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp). (added two links just for reference)

> The scale() method increases or decreases the size of an element (according to the parameters given for the **width and height**).

**Syntax**

```
The scale() function is specified with either one or two values, 
which represent the amount of scaling to be applied in each direction.

scale(sx)

scale(sx, sy)
```

```css
.material-icons-outlined,
.material-icons.material-icons--outlined {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Outlined';
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight:100;
}

.icons_scale{
  transform: scale(0.5); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500|Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp">
</head>

<body>

  <section id="outlined">
    <h2>Outlined</h2>
    <i class="material-icons material-icons--outlined icons_scale">assignment</i>
  </section>
  
</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually, the stroke-width property is used to set the thickness of a line, text, or outline of an element inside the SVG tag. In this case, changing the font size will fix it.

Comment: but without decreasing font size?

Comment: @SreehariAvikkal If I understand your problem properly, then I think using scale can be helpful. Check the updated answer please

Comment: sorry. I want to decrease the stroke width keeping the icon size same.

Comment: Ah my bad, I was thinking differently. Actually, the stroke-width property is used to set the thickness of a line, text, or outline of an element inside the SVG tag. In this case, changing the font size will fix it.

Comment: yeah. Just found out, weight of materials symbols can be modified and icons cannot

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to change the font weight. is icon pattern. you change the font size, reduce the icon size.. what the icon looks like with a smaller border

Answer (score 0):

I think material-icons stroke width cannnot be modified. But instead we can use "material symbols", which can be modified.